# JIRA plugin webwork action is not being find

Tags: jira-plugin, webwork

I am creating a JIRA plugin that will show custom page as per my need. In this page I am creating a page that will show a JQL search result. I have created a web-item and action related to it in Atlassian-plugin.xml as below.

**Atlassian-plugin.xml**

```
<web-item key="search_allissues_link" name="Srarch All Issues" section="custom_links_link/custom_links_section" weight="10">
<label>Search</label>
<link linkId="create_link">/secure/SearchAllIssuesList!hello.jspa</link>
</web-item>


<action
name="com.plugins.jira.customscreensui.action.JQLSearchAction"
alias="SearchAllIssuesList">
<command name="hello" alias="Hello">
<view name="input">templates/all_issues_list.vm</view>
</command>
</action>
```

**This is my Action class**

```
public class JQLSearchAction extends JiraActionSupport{
List<Issue> issueList;
JQLSearchModel jqlSearchModel;
@RequiresXsrfCheck
protected void doValidation() {}

@RequiresXsrfCheck
protected String doExecute() throws Exception
{
jqlSearchModel=new JQLSearchModel();
issueList=jqlSearchModel.getAllIssuesList();
return "input";
}

@RequiresXsrfCheck
protected String doHello() throws Exception
{
jqlSearchModel=new JQLSearchModel();
issueList=jqlSearchModel.getAllIssuesList();
return "input";
}
public List<Issue> getIssueList() {
return issueList;
}
public void setIssueList(List<Issue> issueList) {
this.issueList = issueList;
}
}
```

But I am getting following exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No command 'hello' in action
 Please suggest me the solution if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the access specifier of the command method to `public` shall fix your problem. `public String doHello()`.

I have not tried this code, but looking at the code that's the only thing comes in my mind.

Thank you,

Comment: @SUNILSABALE Happy to hear that. Cheers!